# Uniquely identifying individual views in CardView-RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-cardview

An interesting scenario: I need to uniquely identify a `View` (`EditText` to be precise) in a `RecyclerView` that has `CardView`s.

I have a `RecyclerView` with a ***variable number*** of `CardView`s. Each `CardView` has an `EditText` (`R.id.etCodeBox`). When the user scrolls the `RecyclerView` and enters something in an `EditText` of his choice and clicks a `Button`, I read the value of `R.id.etCodeBox`, and it always returns a blank value (""). Only on the ***first*** `CardView`, I can read back the entered value correctly.

**Relevant code snippet**

```
public boolean verifyCode(Context context, View rootView, int dID, int drID, int userCount)
{
    EditText codeBox = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etCodeBox);

    String enteredCode = codeBox.getText().toString();
    long nowInMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    TextView tvDCount, tvDDate;
    tvDCount = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDCount);
    tvDDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDDate);
    codeBox.setText("");
    if (enteredCode.equals(String.valueOf(dID)))
    {
            :
            :
```

**Relevant Layout snippet**

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvDBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/commonMainListsBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="12dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

                :
                :
                :

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etCodeBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:hint="Code"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword|none"
                    android:focusable="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btClaim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/etCodeBox"
                    android:text="Claim!"/>
                :
                :
                :
```

So, how can I read the correct value from the `EditText` irrespective of the `CardView`'s position? In other words, how do I point uniquely to the 'selected' or 'focused' `CardView`'s `R.id.etCodeBox`?

Comment: set tag to the view of course whats complicated about this?

Comment: How do you mean, @Bhargav? Setting the tag of the `EditText` in `onBind` is easy, but how do I read a particular `CardView`'s `EditText` using `findViewById()` based on the tag and then get the value entered in it? A quick snippet, maybe as an answer, so it can be accepted? If its way too simple, please help me by replying this comment.

Comment: You do use viewholders yes? you already have reference to the edittext no need to do that expensive `findViewById` method everytime you want a  reference to the `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a method in your viewholder class like

```
public String getEtCodeBoxText() {
    return etCodeBox.getText().toString();
}
```

But before you do that you need to hold a reference to that edit text in your viewHolder class

```
public static class MyVIewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final EditText etCodeBox;
    public final View view;

    public VIewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        etCodeBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCodeBox);
    }
}
```

Now instead of actually getting the view and doing findViewById for your EditText, you just get the reference to the viewHolder from the recyclerView by using the many functions provided by recyclerviews (findViewHolderByPosition etc) then call the `getEtCodeBoxText` function and you should be good

So for completion purpose I put here your ViewHolder class code

```
public static class MyVIewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final EditText etCodeBox;
    public final View view;

    public VIewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        etCodeBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCodeBox);
    }
    public String getEtCodeBoxText() {
        return etCodeBox.getText().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. However, your initial comment on tagging `EditText` was clue enough. In combination with `ViewCardHolder`'s `getAdapterPosition()` method, I was able to create many unique tags for other views too. Reading back was also simple, with the `findViewWithTag()` method. I did not later have the need to try out your answer, therefore leaving it un-accepted. Thanks again for all the help, much appreciated.